# Non-fast-forward issue on a branch that only I am working on

Tags: git

I created a branch off of a feature branch that multiple people are working on. So something like this:

```
            /-----my-feat
  /-----new-feat
master
```

`new-feat` continues to be developed on, but `my-feat` is only touched by me. I rebased before trying to push to `origin`, but ended up with a non-fast-forward error. How could this be possible if no one else is touching `my-feat`? I ended up following [this github doc](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/), but found a bunch of merge conflicts in files that I haven't touched, and some in files that I have touched.

My questions are:

1. Was I supposed to fetch and merge to resolve the problem or was this a mistake?
2. How should I proceed? Do I fix the conflicts then push to origin? I hesitant to do so as I'm not sure it will affect others working on any of the other branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: you'll need to force-push (preferably `--force-with-lease`).

> `new-feat` continues to be developed on, but `my-feat` is only touched by me.

But `my-feat` gets pushed back to some centralized server as well, yes?

> I rebased before trying to push to `origin`, but ended up with a non-fast-forward error.

That would be unsurprising.

The thing to know about `git rebase` is that it *copies* commits.

Let's redraw your example to show some actual commits.  Instead of giant 40-character SHA-1 hashes like `face0ff...` and `cafebab...` let's give them one-letter names:

```
...--A--B             <-- master
         \
          C--D--E     <-- new-feat
                 \
                  F   <-- my-feat
```

Now various developers add new commits to `new-feat`:

```
...--A--B                 <-- master
         \
          C--D--E--G--H   <-- new-feat
                 \
                  F       <-- my-feat
```

so you `git rebase` your `my-feat`.  That *copies* commit `F` to a new commit, `F'` (so named because it's a copy of `F`).  There are two big differences between `F` and `F'`, other than the new hash: one is that `F'`'s parent is `H` instead of `E`, and the other is whatever source-code changes have gone in via commits `G` and `H`.  But now the picture looks like this:

```
...--A--B                   <-- master
         \
          C--D--E--G--H     <-- new-feat
                 \     \
                  \     F'  <-- my-feat
                   \
                    F       [abandoned]
```

You still have `F`, saved via your reflogs, for at least 30 days by default.  Meanwhile, though, the *server* you've been pushing to *also* has `F`, because you sent it to them.

You now call up the server and deliver `F'`, your copy of `F`.  All it knows about `F'` is that it has this other hash, parent, source-tree, etc.—all the usual stuff for any commit.  It *does not* know that `F'` is intended as a *replacement* for `F`.  Then you ask the server to set *its* idea of `my-feat` to point to `F'`, and it says:

"If I do that, I'll lose some commits."

This is what "rejected (non-fast-forward)" means: "I'll lose some commits."  Specifically, it will lose `F`, the commit you're intentionally abandoning.

That's fine—so what you need to do is tell that to the server.  (And, somehow, to anyone else *also* using `my-feat`, which is something Git does not help you with.  Since no one else should be using it, you can count the number of people to tell on the fingers of no feet.)  To tell the server that this is OK, you must use some kind of force operation.  The ideal one is `--force-with-lease`, which verifies that *their* `my-feat` does in fact point to `F`, so that `F` is the only commit you'll abandon; but since you're the only one using `my-feat`, you can use the simpler, older, full-force option instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a branch and push it, then rebase this branch and push it, it is not a fast-forward by definition, because you change the history of your branch to be based on another commit than it originally was. As long as this is a branch only you are using and no-one else is basing his branches on, this is not a problem. But if someone took your branch and based his own branches on it, he has to manually rebase those branches onto your newly rewritten history. If you don't care or noone did anything based on your branch, you can simply force-push (`-f`) your branch after the rebase.

Following the GitHub Doc indeed was totally wrong as it didn't apply to your situation. If you have a branch someone else is also pushing to and you are not up-to-date, you have to get those changes into your history by a merge or rebase first, so that no commits are lost because you are overwriting and loosing the commits of the other developer.

In your case you get the non-fast-forward error because you completely rewrote the history of your branch by rebasing. In this situation a simple force-push is the way to go (taken the warning from above into consideration of course).

You should now abort the merge you are at (`git merge --abort`) and simply force-push instead (taken the warning from above into consideration of course, `git push -f origin`).